# How to correctly copy pages from one PDF document to another using iTextPDF 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

The following code is a simplified version of a method that receives a destination pdf document and a source pdf document and copies the pages from the source to the destination. The page copy has to be a little smaller (95%) of the original one since the page in the destination document will receive some extra text as header and footer.

```
try {
    for(int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex<=pdfSource.getNumberOfPages(); ++pageIndex) {
        PdfPage sourcePage = pdfSource.getPage(pageIndex);
        Rectangle sourceRect = sourcePage.getPageSizeWithRotation();

        PdfPage page = pdfDest.addNewPage(PageSize.A4);

        // Transformation matrix
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        AffineTransform transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
                    (page.getPageSize().getWidth() / sourcePage.getWidth()) * 0.95,
                    (page.getPageSize().getHeight() / sourcePage.getHeight()) * 0.95);
        canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        try {
            PdfFormXObject pageCopy = sourcePage.copyAsFormXObject(pdfDestino);
            float x = (float)(page.getPageSize().getWidth()*0.05);
            float y = (float)(page.getPageSize().getHeight()*0.05);
            canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, x, y);
            pageCopy.flush();
        } catch(Exception e) {
           // bla bla bla
        }

        // Reset tansformations
        transformationMatrix = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(
            sourceRect.getWidth() / page.getPageSize().getWidth(),
            sourceRect.getHeight() / page.getPageSize().getHeight()
        );
        canvas.concatMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        canvas.setFillColorRgb(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.65f)
                  .setFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.COURIER), 11);

        // Adding some extra text
        // blah blah blah
    }
} finally {
    pdfSource.close();
}
```

As a general rule, this method will be called many times, since many documents will be appended to the destination PDF document.

All works fine, except when we have a big list of source documents. In this context, big is above 100.

So, when we have a list of, for instance, 30 source documents, all of then are correctly processed and the destination document will have the pages of all the 30 documents.

When this list is longer than 100 documents, we have a OutOfMemory exception. We think there is a memory leak here, but we can't find it.

What are we missing?

Comment: Close your source document before opening a new one.

Comment: @Compass: thanks, but the source document is already being closed at the end of the method. During the transcription of the code to the question, I made a mistake and wrote `pdfDest` instead `pdfSource`. I just edited the code to make it right.

Comment: @Alex, copying pages by inserting them as XObjects into new pages isn't really the best way to copy pages (I'm pretty sure you'll lose any annotations when copying, and you'll need to take extra care when handling bookmarks). It's better to use one of the dedicated `PdfMerger` class or copy through `PdfPage#copyTo`method. And instead of shrinking, increase the page size to account for the header and footer. current method works fine for you, no need to change, just wanted to point out a potential problem later down the line.

Comment: @SamuelHuylebroeck: thanks for your advice. While nobody gives me an answer, I made some tests with `PdfPage.copyTo()`. it worked fine to me, but it did not changed the main problem here, which is the `OutOfMemoryError` exception.

Comment: Hmmmm, don't really have a clear and cut answer for that, try the usual tricks to avoid OutOfMemory errors: batch processing, increasing jvm memory size, making sure you do actually close all documents no longer used etc.

Comment: @AlexSC Can you share (links to) example documents with which one can reproduce the issue in a situation where one would assume that memory should suffice?

Comment: @mkl thanks for your interest, but I don't have the liberty to share those documents. What I cant tell you is that I increased the JVM heap to 1Gb and it allowed me the process to finish with no errors. The resulting document has 109Mb and was built from more than 100 other smaller PDF documents, many of them consisting only of images.